# Databricks : can't install a new cluster on azure databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to install a new cluster on Databricks (I lost the one I used, someone deleted it) and it doesn't work. I have the following message:

```
Time
....
Message
Cluster terminated.Reason:Network Configuration Failure

The data plane network is misconfigured. Please verify that the network for your data plane is configured correctly.

    Instance ID: ...............    
    Error message: Failed to launch HostedContainer{hostPrivateIP=......, 
containerIp=...., 
clusterId=...., resources=InstantiatedResources
{memoryMB=9105, ECUs=3.0, cgroupShares=...}, 
isSpot=false, id=...., instanceId=InstanceId(....), 
state=Pending,instanceType=Standard_DS3_v2, 
metadata=ContainerMetadata(Standard_DS3_v2)}





Because starting the FUSE daemon timed out. 
This may happen because your VMs do not have outbound connectivity to DBFS storage. 
Also consider upgrading your cluster to a later spark version.
```

What can I do ? Maybe I have to unmount ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try and play around with the instance type and see if that helps ? May be this particular instance of the VM is not available in th region . Also check with other version of Pyspark . AFAIK unmounting will not help , but I may be wrong .

Comment: Hello it was a problem with access about the DBFS (security access).